# Proof that Limit of the Log is the Log of the Limit

Tags: calculus, limits

Proof that Limit of the Log is the Log of the Limit. What is the intuition behind this statement?

Comment: Logarithm is a continuous function, and in general, if $\lim_{x \to c} g(x) = b$, and $f$ is continuous at $b$, then $f(\lim_{x \to c} g(x)) = f(b) = \lim_{x \to c} f(g(x))$.

Comment: Many thanks Henry!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Logarithm is a continuous function, and in general, if $\lim\limits_{x \to c} g(x) = b$, and $f$ is continuous at $b$, then $f\left(\lim\limits_{x \to c} g(x)\right) = f(b) = \lim\limits_{x \to c} f\big(g(x)\big)$. – [Henry Swanson](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/55540/henry-swanson)