# The limit of the logarithm is equal to the logarithm of the limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

my exercise is to proof the following:
if $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a positive sequence, and if
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty} x_n =x,\,\, \mbox {where } x>0$$
then
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty} \log x_n=\log x$$
I have no idea how that works and I would be happy if someone could help me.

EDIT:
I am not allowed to use the information that the logarithm is a countinous function.

Comment: The logarithm is a *continuous* function ...

Comment: Yes I knew that already, but i don't really how that helps. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Write down the definition of continuity at the point $x$. It is exactly what you need.

Comment: @MartinR: that depends on which definition of continuity you use.

Comment: What did you try? Did you look through the relevant definitions one more time? If not that might bring some clarity.

Comment: So far we have not defined what a continous function is. So I am not allowed to use this. Are there any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, think about

$$| \log x_n -\log x| = \left|\log \frac{x_n}{x} \right| < \epsilon.$$

It would be implied by $e^{-\epsilon} <\frac{x_n}{x} < e^\epsilon.$

Context would help here.  If you already have a theorem about the quotient of limits, then you're about done.

Comment: Actually you need $e^{-\epsilon} < \frac{x_n}{x} < e^\epsilon$

Comment: @MartinR  True.  Maybe I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your question might be a duplicate or similar to 
[this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/787484/proof-that-limit-of-the-log-is-the-log-of-the-limit)

> Logarithm is a continuous function, and in general, if $\lim\limits_{x \to c} g(x) = b$, and $f$ is continuous at $b$, then $f\left(\lim\limits_{x \to c} g(x)\right) = f(b) = \lim\limits_{x \to c} f\big(g(x)\big)$. – [Henry Swanson](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/55540/henry-swanson)

Comment: I am not allowed to use the information that the logarithm is a countinous function. Without this restriction, the exercise would be easy. But thanks for answering!

Comment: Please add it to the initial condition, so that the others would try to do it differently